# How is it possible to use the for-each loop for classes that do not implement Iterable

Tags: java, collections, foreach, interface, iterable

I was reading Collections From **The Complete Reference** and then I encountered this statement

**The Collection Interface**

> The Collection interface is the foundation upon which the Collections
>   Framework is built because it must be implemented by any class that
>   defines a collection. Collection is a generic interface that has this
>   declaration: `interface Collection<E>`. Here, E specifies the type of
>   objects that the collection will hold. Collection extends the Iterable
>   interface.This means that all collections can be cycled through  by
>   use of the for-each style for loop.(Recall that only classes that
>   implement Iterable can be cycled through by the for).

In the last two lines,it is written that only those classes which implement the Iterable interface can be cycled through the for loop.
But,I guess that the object class does not implement the iterable interface,then how we are able to use the for-each loop in case of Strings,integers etc.

Comment: `Recall that only classes that implement Iterable can be cycled through by the for.` And arrays, let's not forget about arrays.

Answer (score 5):

That's true. `java.lang.Object` does not implement the `Iterable<T>` interface.

We can iterate through objects because the object holder (e.g. `Collection`) implements the `Iterable<T>` automatically, not necessarily the objects part of the collection.

Comment: @Crazyjavahcking-Oh,,,got it buddy.

Comment: Why so much text in bold?

Answer (score 3):

If you are iterating through a collection of strings, or integers, it is the *collection* that is iterable, not the string or the integer. The items in the iteration don't have to be iterable; the container does.

Answer (score 3):

You wouldnt ever want to iterate through an integer, nor could you ever do such a thing.  An integer is a single entity, whereas the iterable interface is in reference to a colleciton of entities.  For example:

```
List<Integer> intList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (Integer i : intList) {
   System.out.println(i);
}
```